# Issue in increasing the ubuntu disk size (vitualbox image)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, size, virtualbox, disk

My ubuntu disk size is 52.4 GB, but the disk is still showing 11G. Any suggestions for the below?
    root@mubuntu:~# fdisk -l
    ------------
    Disk /dev/sda: 52.4 GB, 52428800000 bytes
    255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 6374 cylinders, total 102400000 sectors
    Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
    Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
    Disk identifier: 0x000ac38c

```
   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048      499711      248832   83  Linux
/dev/sda2          499712      501757        1023   8e  Linux LVM
/dev/sda3          501758    23486463    11492353    5  Extended
/dev/sda5          501760    23486463    11492352   8e  Linux LVM

root@mubuntu:~# df -h
Filesystem                    Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/mubuntu--vg-root   11G  9.5G  161M  99% /
none                          4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev                          991M  4.0K  991M   1% /dev
tmpfs                         201M  1.1M  200M   1% /run
none                          5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none                         1001M     0 1001M   0% /run/shm
none                          100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
/dev/sda1                     236M   66M  158M  30% /boot
```

--> Does the below look good?

```
root@mubuntu:~# pvscan
  PV /dev/sda5   VG mubuntu-vg   lvm2 [10.96 GiB / 0    free]
  Total: 1 [10.96 GiB] / in use: 1 [10.96 GiB] / in no VG: 0 [0   ]

root@mubuntu:~# pvdisplay
  --- Physical volume ---
  PV Name               /dev/sda5
  VG Name               mubuntu-vg
  PV Size               10.96 GiB / not usable 2.00 MiB
  Allocatable           yes (but full)
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              2805
  Free PE               0
  Allocated PE          2805
  PV UUID               upfW6u-dHEc-0ub9-0FAJ-hmFW-10lK-po2nwS

root@mubuntu:~# vgdisplay
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               mubuntu-vg
  System ID             
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  4
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                2
  Open LV               2
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               10.96 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              2805
  Alloc PE / Size       2805 / 10.96 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       0 / 0   
  VG UUID               v9h4EA-xJbR-vEff-qsEk-AvHE-apfK-1j4YI2

root@mubuntu:~# lvdisplay
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/mubuntu-vg/root
  LV Name                root
  VG Name                mubuntu-vg
  LV UUID                Os34MI-SJz0-DTPa-2104-xof8-F4Wm-sy0XfM
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time mubuntu, 2014-08-30 15:51:45 -0500
  LV Status              available
  # open                 1
  LV Size                10.46 GiB
  Current LE             2677
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           252:0

  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Path                /dev/mubuntu-vg/swap_1
  LV Name                swap_1
  VG Name                mubuntu-vg
  LV UUID                FmnrhR-7i3c-jMaK-dmqr-OMA3-S3jv-oetzdS
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Creation host, time mubuntu, 2014-08-30 15:51:46 -0500
  LV Status              available
  # open                 2
  LV Size                512.00 MiB
  Current LE             128
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     auto
  - currently set to     256
  Block device           252:1
```

Comment: you must have done dynamic allocation of the hard disk

Comment: Yes Dynamic allocation was done.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you set virtual disk to dynamic allocation in virtual box, virtual box does not occupy all the space at once i.e. in your case you had set up 52.4GB as the size of virtual disk this is the max size the virtual hard disk can take. When virtual box create a dynamically allocated disk it starts with the least size of say may be 100KB but as the content in your virtual OS starts to increase the disk grows, and it grows to the size you have set. But whenever you check the size of the hard disk from inside the virtual OS it will show you size as the max size you have set.

Comment: I tested and created a file , but it gave error "No space left on device"                                                         root@mubuntu:~# dd if=/dev/urandom of=temp.txt bs=1G count=1
dd: error writing â€˜temp.txtâ€™: No space left on device
1+0 records in
0+0 records out
472928256 bytes (473 MB) copied, 110.87 s, 4.3 MB/s..Only 473 MB was copied.

Comment: One problem I see that pvdisplay doesn't show all the partition, and only show /dev/sda5. Not sure why?